# localStorage clears after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

For some reason every time I try to save something to my localStorage under the attribute `Reservas`, if I refresh the page the data in localStorage will be wiped out.

I already used a similar method to store data from the registration form on my app (some other page) and it stores it perfectly. I don't know why this does not work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var userlog;
  var reserva = {}
  var reservas = []
  var dia_semana_input = document.getElementById('sel_dia')
  var refeicao_input = document.getElementById('sel_tipo')
  var prato_input = document.getElementById('sel_prato')

  var error_fix = {
    nome: "1",
    dia: "1",
    refeicao: "1",
    prato: "1"
  }
  reservas.push(error_fix)
  localStorage.setItem("Reservas", JSON.stringify(reservas));
  var utilizadores = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('utilizadores'))
  console.log(utilizadores)
  console.log(reservas)
  reservas = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Reservas'))
  /* verificação para mais tarde utilizar nas reservas*/
  for (var i = 0; i < utilizadores.length; i++) {
    if (utilizadores[i].ativo == 1) {
      userlog = utilizadores[i].Username
    }
  }

  $("#btnReservar").click(function() {
    /*Stores object into array */
    /*which then stores into local storage(?)*/
    var dia_semana = dia_semana_input.value
    var refeicao = refeicao_input.value
    var prato = prato_input.value
    for (var i = 0; i < reservas.length; i++) {
      if (reservas[i].nome == userlog && reservas[i].dia == dia_semana) {
        console.log("primeiro")
        alert('Já existe uma reserva para esse dia!')
      } else {
        console.log("segundo")
        reserva.nome = userlog
        reserva.dia = dia_semana
        reserva.refeicao = refeicao
        reserva.prato = prato
        reservas.push(reserva)
        console.log(reservas)
      }
    }

    localStorage.setItem('Reservas', JSON.stringify(reservas))
  });
})
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Papipone do you have a script that auto-tags first time posts with this, regardless of content? Surely you didn't come to that conclusion without a poorly written, buggy script?

Comment: You're calling `setItem()` *right* before you first call `getItem()`, so you're probably overwriting the existing value

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null` on `var utilizadores = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('utilizadores'))`, try setting `var utilizadores = []` and it will work

Comment: @Aron I do not use any script. Thank you to report it to me though. I will make an effort in order to help new comers. I generally copy paste the sentence for the first post of new contributors (review queue). I will change my behavior.

Comment: Thank you ! IT DID WORK   my first "setItem" was overwritting the last one !

Answer (score 1):

You have a call to `setItem` with that key. That will cause it to be set to the values that are in `reservas`. Perhaps you want to call `getItem`?